# Natural Boundary Conditions in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

Can we use **natural boundary conditions** (if suppose I can't expressed my boundary conditions explicitly i.e. in terms of **essential boundary conditions**) in **NDSolve**.

I am trying to solve a **boundary value problem (PDE)** where at one end the boundary condition are expressed in terms of **force** (here force is a function of the **dependent variable**).

Though I found a link [NDSolve Dankwerts boundary conditions with changing discrete variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98787/ndsolve-dankwerts-boundary-conditions-with-changing-discrete-variable) where a natural boundary condition was used in NDSolve.

I want to make sure whether it is possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your PDE along with boundary conditions?